# Alphabetize all but one category

Tags: categories

I have my categories set to sort alphabetically:

```
<?php if (is_category()) { 
     $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc'); 
  } 
?>
```

I want to exclude one category so that it sorts by date. I tried this but it made all the cats come up blank:

```
<?php if (is_category()) { 
    $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&exclude=15'); 
   }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `query_posts` should not be used. you should be using `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts`. In which template are you using this code

Comment: ThemeMeme's Cassie

Comment: What I meant is is it index.php, category.php etc

Comment: Sorry, in archive.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an else to the condition along with adding the excluded category id in the `is_category()` call.  You will also need to include/exclude that particular category depending on the condition that is true:

NOTE:  you probably want to avoid using `query_posts` and use `WP_Query()`  [Reference here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

```
 <?php 
    if (is_category(15)) {
        $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=date&order=asc&cat=15'); 
    }

   else {
     if(is_category()) { 
        $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&cat=-15'); 
       } 
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: `query_posts` should not be used

Comment: @PieterGoosen:  he already had it in his code, I used it to clarify his own code as all he needed/wanted was the condition.

Comment: I just always think that someone must be made aware of something this wrong. I always make the OP aware of his problem and rectify it in my answer. The big thing here is, even the codex clearly states hat `query_posts` should not be used.

Comment: @PieterGoosen:  Pieter, I don't disagree but sometimes people just need help to solve a specific problem they have with functioning code.  I think it's great that you point it out and you should continue to do so. As a matter of fact, based on all the times I've seen you comment about it, I've stopped using it in my own code.  Thanks for that !  :-)